# I have troubles running React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I am just starting with learning React and I already have trouble using it (maybe i am just stupid but i ran through so many videos and solution but that still didn't work). I am just trying to type "Hello World" in my document.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    
    
    <script type="text/babel" src="index.js"></script>    <!-- Also doesn't work with type="module" -->
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
import React from "react";

function Message() {
  return <h1>Hello world</h1>;
}

export default Message;
```

So i added module type to "package.json" under `"version": "0.1.0",` and that still didn't work.
I don't think if this is a problem but i made my files like this: [image: [Here's image of files locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXkYq.jpg)]

Comment: There are [many ways to create a React app](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project). You could just use [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/). There also is a [Getting Started guide by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started). You can also [add it to a website very easily in a minute](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html).

Comment: After that you can execute this command to install dependencies `cd your-project && npm i` and use `npm run dev` to run your project localy.

Comment: @Martin why do you have those files `index.html` and `index.js` outside your React folder? And `src` is your working directory you usually don't wanna modify the rest unless you know what you are doing

Comment: @RyukShi Thank you for your advice, i will have that in mind.

Comment: @Aleksandar I through I can just install react and use it with any other file from other locations. Just like you are applying images in document with src location from another folder.

Comment: @Mushroomator Thank you for your comment, I think I will continue using create-react-app.